# vuetify 1.1 how to display a tooltip on v-text-filed prepend icon?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I kown it's now possible with the new 1.1. version ... but there is no example ...

where toe set the slot 'prepend' ? and where to set the tooltip text ? (  tag ? )

```
     <v-card-text class="grow">
          <v-text-field disabled value="john.doe@example.com" :label="Email" prepend-icon="email"></v-text-field>
          ....
     </v-card-text>
```

**UPDATE**

tested :

```
                <v-text-field disabled v-bind:value="user.email" :label="$t('lang.views.home.section4.email')" prepend-icon="email">
                  {{ user.email }}
                  <v-tooltip slot="append" bottom>
                    <v-icon slot="activator" >edit</v-icon>
                    <span>Edit</span>
                  </v-tooltip>
                </v-text-field>
```

without any success

Comment: yes , sorry I did not get it before ... thanks for link...

Comment: duplicated question ... but not the good answer ... test it wo any success... this is right for an icon added to the text field , not for thev- text-field with :rpepebd-cion...

Comment: @erwin if u remove disabled from input it will work tho. I mean everything in your example work except tooltip when input disabled

Comment: sorry .. my fault ... it runs well .. I updated the wrong file LOL in which the text-field was disabled .. need to be readonly !